# Flashbuilder 4 and Clearcase plugin

Tags: eclipse, clearcase, flashbuilder4, clearcase-remote-client

I am running flash builder 4 plugin on eclipse Ganymede 3.4.2

I'm trying to install ClearCase plugin for eclipse but it is giving me no repository found errors. Has anyone run into this? I saw a workaround on a Java forum but it doesn't work in flex view.

Also, I'm willing to even install ClearCase remote client 7.1 bit I can't even get the IBM installation manager installed. Their instructions are impossible. I'm at my wits end.

Can anyone possibly lend a hand? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClearCase plugin and CCRC are two very different programs:

- ClearCase plugin is a full ClearCase integration with Eclipse, made to work within a full ClearCase client installation.
  can be installed through the p2 update site mentioned in the 

  [Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter (For Eclipse), Version 7.5.0.0](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674) page:

  - SCM Adapter for Eclipse on Windows
    http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/windows/
  - SCM Adapter for Eclipse on Solaris/Linux
    http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/unix/
- [CCRC client](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224586) is a client for a CCRC web server (which in turn with the ClearCase VOB server): no actual ClearCase client locally installed, no cleartool, no nothing: just a lightweight ClearCase client.
  You cannot use a CCRC client if you already have a full ClearCase client installed.
  You cannot use a CCRC client if you don't have a CCRC server somewhere listening for the request of that (CCRC) client.

Comment: The SCM Adapter is what I was trying to get work. I followed the steps but that is when I was getting the repository not found error. I've seen the bug elsewhere on my online search but haven't found a good solution yet.